# "That was rude from your side" Does it sound natural?

Tags: collocations

A person did something wrong or bad. Can I use this phrase to express my concern?
"That was rude from your side. You should've been more considerate".
If not kindly provide your examples that would sound natural. Thank you.

Comment: That was rude **of you**.

Comment: Or **on your part**, but not 'from your side'.

Comment: @KateBunting  You might say 'that was rude on your part', when discussing the apportionment of blame in somebody's argument with another person, or oneself, but it might be a little odd if intended as a short rebuke for something just said.

Comment: "From your side" is common usage in Indian English, but not in British or American English. See for example https://theieltstutor.edublogs.org/2014/11/26/indianisms-and-the-ielts/